# SQL: COUNT() grouped results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

this is my current query:

```
SELECT locationname, eventid
FROM events
GROUP BY locationname
ORDER BY locationname ASC
```

As you can see it's grouped by locationname because there are several rows with the same locationname.

In the output i just need a list of "distinct" (grouped) locations but behind every location there should be the total amount of each location.

So if in "events" are 4 locationsname with "Congress Center NYC" the output should be "Congress Center NYC (4)".

Is there a way to expand the query with a COUNT()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a straightforward aggregate query.

```
SELECT locationname, COUNT(*) number
  FROM events
 GROUP BY locationname
 ORDER BY locationname
```

If you want specific formatting, you can get it using this first line of your query.

```
 SELECT CONCAT(locationname, ' (', COUNT(*), ')')
```

Answer (score 2):

Selecting `COUNT(locationname)` should do what you want. I.e.

```
SELECT locationname, COUNT(locationname)
FROM events
GROUP BY locationname
ORDER BY locationname ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query example there is "event_id", when you add grouping you will receive "event_id" of the first occurred row with the same "locationame", 
you can use group_concat to get all events and perform count in the same time

```
SELECT locationname, group_concat(eventid), count(eventid) as number
FROM events
GROUP BY locationname
ORDER BY locationname ASC
```

also you can use concat function to have the output exactly as you wrote

```
SELECT concat(locationname, ' (', count(*), ')')
FROM events
GROUP BY locationname
ORDER BY locationname ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT locationname, locationname+quotename(COUNT(distinct locationname),'()')
FROM events GROUP BY locationname
```

Please let me know in comments if it didn't work
Note: Before post the qn Please mention which kind of database you are asked for